# Corrupted file problem

Tags: 11.04, filesystem

Is there any way to decorrupt a file in Ubuntu 11.04? I think the file might have got encrypted when I shutdown my system but didn't decrypt correctly when I started up. Or, does Ubuntu auto backup anywhere? Anything that might help me restore a lost file could help.

The filesystem is ext4. Its only one file that not working correctly, and it stopped working after I had to manually shutdown my system.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. I am flagging this for closure. Regards,

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try file system checking utilities.. "fsck" the partition/volume the encrypted file in question resides on. You *may* need to boot off a LiveCD or something to do that check. Once that's done, try decrypting your file again. If that doesn't work, I fear you may be SOL. But maybe others will know tricks.

Good luck friend!

Comment: Its ext4. Its only one file that not working correctly, and it stopped working after I had to manually shutdown my system.